# Conditional expectation problem: Finding $E[N | G = 0]$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

I have the following problem:

> In the country Maxvierk the number $N$ of children of a randomly selected family, and the number $G$ of girls among the children, are given by the following joint probability mass function:
>
> [image]
>
> Determine $\mathbb{E}[N|G = g]$ and $\text{Var}[N|G = g]$.

I began by solution as follows:

$$\begin{align} E[N | G = 0] &= \sum_{n = 0}^4 n P(N = n | G = 0) \\ &= (0) \left( \dfrac{1}{5} \right) + (1) \left( \dfrac{1}{10} \right) + (2) \left( \dfrac{1}{20} \right) + (3) \left( \dfrac{1}{40} \right) + (4) \left( \dfrac{1}{80} \right) \\ &= \dfrac{13}{40} \end{align}$$

However, the solution has that $E[N | G = 0] = \dfrac{26}{31}$.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track.  However $E[N|G=0]$ is actually given by a quotient,

$$ \sum_{n=0}^4 n P(N=n \textrm{ and } G=0) \over P(G=0). $$

You've computed the numerator.  The denominator is $31/80$, and dividing gives the result you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Isn't $P(G = 0) = 1/5$?

Comment: For instance, for $E[N | G = 4]$, I get $$\begin{align} \sum_{n = 0}^4 n P(N = n | G = 4) &= \sum_{n = 0}^4 n \dfrac{P(N = n, G = 4}{P(G = 4)} \\ &= (0)(0) + (1)(0) + (2)(0) + (3)(0) + (4) \left( \dfrac{1}{80} \right) \\ &= \dfrac{1/20}{1/5} = \dfrac{1}{4},  \end{align}$$ but, according to the solutions, it should be $E[N | G = 4] = 4$

Comment: You're welcome.   To get $P(G = g)$ for some $g$ you have to sum $P(N = n, G = g)$ for different values of $n$, which means summing the values in a column of the table. For example $P(G = 0)$ is the sum of the whole left column, $1/5 + 1/10 + 1/20 + 1/40 + 1/80 = 31/80$.  Similarly $P(G = 4) = 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1/80 = 1/80$.

Comment: Ahh, of course; after all, $P(G = g)$ *is* the marginal probability mass function, so therefore: $$P(G = g) = \sum_{n = 0}^4 P(G = g, N = n) = \sum_{n = 0}^4 P(N = n) P(G = g | N = n)$$ (Otherwise known as marginalizing out the $N$.)